# create a user mapping without password

Tags: database, postgresql, nosql, postgresql-11

I am trying to create a user mapping in PostgreSQL without a password, but I am encountering an error that says "ERROR: password is required" when I try to access a table. Here is the command that I used to create the user mapping:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING for app_user SERVER testmachine02 OPTIONS (user 'test');
```

I also created a pgpass file with the following entries:

```
localhost:5432:local_db:app_user:app_user123
192.168.56.10:5432:admin:admin:admin123
192.168.56.10:5432:remote_db:test:test123
testmachine02:5432:local_db:test:test123
```

Despite these steps, I am still unable to access the table without a password. How can I create a user mapping without a password and access the table?

Answer (score 0):

If this were PostgreSQL v13 or better, [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html#id-1.11.7.47.11) would tell you what to do:

> Only superusers may create or modify user mappings with the `sslcert` or `sslkey` settings.
>
> Only superusers may connect to foreign servers without password authentication, so always specify the `password` option for user mappings belonging to non-superusers.
>
> A superuser may override this check on a per-user-mapping basis by setting the user mapping option `password_required 'false'`, e.g.,
>
> ```
> ALTER USER MAPPING FOR some_non_superuser SERVER loopback_nopw
> OPTIONS (ADD password_required 'false');
> ```

But in PostgreSQL v11, there is not way to connect without a password unless you are a superuser.

Comment: I already tried it but not working as well. ERROR:  invalid option "password_required"

Comment: I didn't see that is way v11. I fixed the answer.

Comment: I have seen the same issue you fixed but it was with version 9, not with  the version 11.

Comment: I didn't fix anything; not sure what you mean.

Comment: just not working for me, here the error  I am getting: ERROR: invalid option "password_required"

Comment: Yes, because you are using PostgreSQL v11. I updated my answer to say that it doesn't work for v11. You could upgrade.

Comment: I upgraded the to the version 13 still getting the same error:local_db=# create user mapping for app_user server testmachine02 OPTIONS (password_required 'false');
ERROR:  invalid option "password_required"
HINT:  Valid options in this context are: user, password
local_db=# create user mapping for app_user server testmachine02 OPTIONS (ADD password_required 'false');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "password_required"
LINE 1: ...ng for app_user server testmachine02 OPTIONS (ADD password_r...

Comment: I just tried it, and it works fine. You must have connected to an older server by mistake. Try `SELECT version();`.

Comment: it worked for me with the version 14 and also without using 'ADD' so just ALTER USER MAPPING FOR some_non_superuser SERVER loopback_nopw
OPTIONS (password_required 'false');                                                                                but I am getting this error below:                                                                                   local_db=> select * from employee;
ERROR:  could not connect to server "testmachine02"
DETAIL:  connection to server at "192.168.56.10", port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied.

Comment: That's a different problem, one of authentication. Open another question for that if you cannot figure out how to configure authentication.